# Why does Save change my data precision?

Tags: precision-and-accuracy

I have some data from some Mathematica program, and it appears that the precision of the data has been slightly changes when I save the data and reload it again.

```
Clear[data]

DumpGet["data.dump"]

Tally[Precision /@ Flatten[data]]
(* {{MachinePrecision, 100000}} *)

Save["data.dat", data];

Clear[data]

Get["data.dat"];

Tally[Precision /@ Flatten[data]]
(* {{MachinePrecision, 99971}, {15.9546, 27}, {15.9546, 1}, {15.9546, 1}} *)
```

So why does `Save` change the precision?

The data.dump is [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24667921/Data%20for%20Mathematica%20StackExchange%20Questions/data%20precision%20change%20after%20save/data.dump) and data.dat is [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24667921/Data%20for%20Mathematica%20StackExchange%20Questions/data%20precision%20change%20after%20save/data.dat). I'm using OS X 10.10.2 .

Comment: this might be enlightening: `Select[data, Precision[#] =!= MachinePrecision &  ]`

Comment: FWIW The arbitrary precision values are all complex numbers with both parts smaller than `$MinMachineNumber`, eg. `1.5*10^-323 - 5.*10^-324 I`